# Searching for Command Prompt Parameters?

Tags: windows, cmd

Is there anyway to search command prompt parameters in a general sense. Or are we hostage to the documentation of such programs? For example in the command prompt I type explorer or notepad... but if I put the first parameter as a file path it will open that file path for me... how am I supposed to know this parameter input exists and perhaps there is a bunch of other parameter fields I am unaware of. Is there anyway to search program parameters systematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows programs are responsible for processing their own command line parameters, and they can do so in any way they please.  (It is common to hand off tokenization to the C runtime library, but not mandatory.)

This gives the programmer maximum flexibility, but does mean that if the programmer has not documented the command line there is no straightforward way to reverse engineer it after the fact.

(UNIX isn't very much different; the tokenization is handled by the shell, but the rest of the processing is the applications responsibility.  In VMS, by contrast, the entire command-line processing is handled by the shell, based on syntax information that must be embedded in the application.)

It is conventional for an application to provide a command-line syntax summary in response to one or more of the following options:

```
application /?
application -?
application /help
application -help
application --?
application --help
```

(Arranged approximately from most-common to least-common; the variants with two hyphens are usually only found in software that has been ported from UNIX.)

I haven't looked for actual statistics, but my impression is that the majority of command-line applications (perhaps 80% or more) do provide such a summary.  It is less common for GUI applications.

Failing that, you can sometimes find command-line options by looking for strings in the executable file.  Microsoft provides a utility that does this, `strings.exe`, downloadable from their web site.  (Of course, knowing the existence of a possible command-line option doesn't necessarily mean you'll be able to figure out what it does!)

If you have access to the source code, or are skilled at disassembly, that may provide another option if you are desperate enough.

Comment: link to strings.exe https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No. Though you can always try `programname /?`.

Notepad takes a single filename only OR takes `/p filename` ... (you can see the command in txtfiles print entry in the registry).

Here's something from Windows 98 Explorer's it still the same.

```
Explorer 
explorer [/n] [/e][,/root,object][[,/select],subobject]

None Explorer rooted at the Desktop 
/n Opens a new window. 
/e Explorer View (default if nothing else is on the command line.) 
/root,object Starts Explorer with object the top item (normally Desktop is the top item). Eg: explorer /e,/root,c:\Starts Explorer with the C drive as the only drive available. 
/select,subobject Selects the specified subobject. 

Replaceable parameters are %1 (one) which is the short file or folder name and %l (L) which is the long file name.

/IDLIST
This is an additional parameter that means a Windows internal structure is being passed. eg:

Explorer.exe /e,/idlist,%I
The %I is a replacable parameter representing an IDLIST.

Rooted Views
To open an explorer item that starts with a special folder as the top folder use the following syntax.

Where the special folder is a sub folder of the desktop

explorer /e,root,::{CLSID of special folder}

Where the special folder is a sub folder of another special folder (usually, if not always My Computer) 

explorer /e,root,::{CLSID of parent}/::{CLSID of special folder}

Where the special folder is part of the file system

explorer /e,root,path to folder

See Namespaces on the Icons Page for a list of CLSIDs for special folders.

Examples
Note that /select is inconsistent. Sometime the / is required, sometimes it should be left out, and sometimes it doesn't matter.

Starts explorer with the Windows folder opened and selected.

explorer /e,select,c:\windows
Starts explorer with Windows the top level folder and command opened and selected.

explorer /e,/root,c:\windows,select,c:\windows\command
Starts explorer with Windows the top level folder and Tips.txt showing instead of the file listing.

explorer /e,/root,c:\windows,select,c:\windows\tips.txt
Starts explorer with My Computer the top level folder and all branches except for drives collapsed. 

explorer /e,/root,::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}
Starts explorer with C:\ the top level folder. 

explorer /e,/root,c:\
Starts the Dial Up Networking folder in folder view.

explorer.exe ::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}\::{992cffa0-f557-101a-88ec-00dd010ccc48}
```